# $K$ compact $\implies K^{\epsilon}:=\{x: d(x,K)\le\epsilon\}$ compact?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. I was wondering under what condition on the space do we have that for any $K\subset X$ compact we have that $K^{\epsilon}:=\{x: d(x,K)\le\epsilon\}$ is also compact. Should the space be locally compact?

Comment: Do you mean $K^{\epsilon}:=\{x: d(x,K)\le\epsilon\}$? Otherwise the set is *open.*

Comment: Oh yes thanks. I will change it

Comment: No, in general metric space this fails.  The set is closed and bounded, though, so in certain metric spaces that is enough to imply compact.  No, locally compact is not enough.

Comment: If $X$ is compact, this is true.

Comment: That condition implies that the unit ball is compact. In *linear* spaces that is only the case if the space is finite dimensional.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete metric $d(x,y)=1$ iff $x\neq y$. $K=\{1\}$ is compact and $K^{1}$ is not.

Comment: locally compact doesn't work. Consider the discrete metric space on an infinite set, which is locally compact, but doesn't satisfy the above criterion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to the Heine-Borel-property.

If $X$ satisfies the Heine-Borel-property (i.e. closed + bounded implies compact), then clearly $K^\varepsilon$ is closed and bounded for a compact $K \subseteq X$, therefore compact.

If $X$ satisfies your property, then any closed and bounded set $X \supseteq A\neq \emptyset$ is contained in one $ \{a\}^\varepsilon$, for some $a \in A$, $\varepsilon$ sufficiently large.  Since $\{a\}$ clearly is compact, so is $ \{a\}^\varepsilon$ and therefore $A$, being a closed subset of a compact
set.